# Use menu item for open another interface controller

Tags: swift, watchkit, gesture

I'm trying to add the possibility to use Force Touch for opening another Interface Controller on my Apple Watch. Is it possible to use the Menu object through the Menu Item for launching another Interface Controller? And if yes, how can I? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to create an `IBAction` for your Menu Item and call the desired navigation function inside that `IBAction`. I will show you code for using `presentController`, but you can use any other available navigation function from `WatchKit`.

```
@IBAction func presentOtherInterfaceController() {
    self.presentController(withName: "MyOtherInterfaceController", context: nil)
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: I still have a problem... After have implemented it and when I'm pushing on the menu Item it's not opening the other interface controller. Should I implement something else?

Comment: Are you sure both your IBAction and Interface Controller identifier are set up properly? What happens if you use `pushController` instead of `presentController`?  I'll test this myself as well in the meantime.

Comment: I just tested this code on a Simulator and it works perfectly, so it seems you have an issue with something not set up properly in `Storyboard`.